# Excel: Number of weeks, when the income of weekends are more than the income of weekdays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example I have this sheet:
[image]

I want to calculate the number of weeks when the income of weekends are more than the income of weekdays.

*(Income of weekends = Income of Sunday's + Saturday's income)*
*(Income of weekdays = Income Monday's + Tuesday's + Wednesday's + Thursday's + Friday's income)*

For example in week 1: weekdays earning = 10$, weekends earning = 15$. Weekends earning > Weekday's earning

I'm not allowed to use helper columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the layout is absolutely regular in full weeks as in the sample, I would use Offset to get the weekends and weeks as ranges, then Subtotal to get the sum of each of them as arrays, then compare them and finally use Sumproduct to get the count of those where weekend pay is greater than week's pay:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&INT(COUNT(B:B)/7)))*7-2,0,2))>
SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&INT(COUNT(B:B)/7)))*7-7,0,5))))
```

The Row and Indirect are used to work out how many complete weeks there are, and so how many times the process has to be repeated.

[image]

**Note** - uses Indirect and Offset which are volatile and may give rise to performance issues with large sheets.

Comment: I tried your formula [in this sheet](https://imgur.com/a/3nC6b2G) and didnt't work for me.
Note: If I write 100$ in Saturday's earning instead of Sunday's it works fine.

Comment: I tried those 7 numbers and it worked for me, not sure what is happening there.

Comment: Ah yes I think it's likely that you copied the formula from another cell and it changed B2 into B1, I should probably have fixed the ranges e.g. $B$2 and $B:$B to stop that happening.

Comment: Tried again now it's fine. English is a foreign language for me, maybe I mistranslated a formula name. Thank you for your help.